# Default Text style in android Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

In my App I have a fragment with Gridview in it to show several lists by swiping left / right in the form.

I use default Grdiview w/o customizing its items.

Here is the layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
    tools:context="com.example.ees.aviacheck.checklist$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Test Text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/section_label"
        tools:ignore="SpUsage" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My problem is that this stuff:

```
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
```

is not considered at all - I get default text style and all these tags are ignored completely whatever I put there.

Do I really need to customize item in a separate item.xml to get what I need or are there any other ways?..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes you should customize your grid items with that text attributes..

Comment: @Santanu Sur: thanks! so, it means, make a separate xml for the item and make Gridview out of these items, correct?

Comment: yep you are correct.. or you can do it programatically i suggest you do in the xml of items.. ..